# how to set different font in xmgrace batch file

Tags: xmgrace

How do I change the font of `xaxis`, `yaxis` `label` and `title` to (arial for example) in `xmgrace` batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

To change the x axis font add the following line to your batch file:

```
xaxis label font 4
```

Font number 4 is mapped to Helvetica. The full list of available fonts are described in the documentation at http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Xmgr/doc/fonts.html

Arial is not included, since it has a proprietary license. Grace is licensed under the [GNU General Public License](http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Grace/doc/GPL.html) and therefore doesn't use proprietary fonts. [Helvetica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetica) is a good sans serif alternative and is often [recommended](http://biotheory.umd.edu/v1.0/tip.html) for scientific publications.

**Changing the default font mappings:**

If you want to change the default font mapping you can do so by creating a new folder (assuming you use GNU/Linux) at

```
~/.grace/templates/
```

then creating a new Default.agr file

```
cp /usr/share/grace/templates/Default.agr ~/.grace/templates/
```

and modifying the lines relating to font mapping:
e.g.

```
...
@map font 0 to "Helvetica", "Helvetica"
@map font 1 to "Helvetica-Oblique", "Helvetica-Oblique"
@map font 2 to "Helvetica-Bold", "Helvetica-Bold"
@map font 3 to "Helvetica-BoldOblique", "Helvetica-BoldOblique"
@map font 4 to "Times-Roman", "Times-Roman"
@map font 5 to "Times-Italic", "Times-Italic"
...
```

Now whenever you create a new plot Helvetica should be used by default.